# Taylor's Remainder Theorem Explanation Question

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, approximation

I'm working through how Taylor's Remainder Theorem works using [this](https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m8w10/public_html/m8l02.pdf) guide, and on page 2, I saw something that made me puzzled.

The first step is to acknowledge that there is some value of K for which

$$\sin(1/2) = T_3(1/2)+K(1/2)^4$$

Where $T_3$ is the third-order Maclaurin polynomial for $\sin(x)$.

After applying Rolle's theorem up to the fourth derivative, we get:

$$K = \frac{\sin^{(4)}(c)}{24}$$

But then it says that:

$$|\sin(1/2) - T_3(1/2)| ≤ K(1/2)^4≤\frac{1}{24 * 2^4}$$

I don't get why the $|\sin(1/2) - T_3(1/2)|$ would ever be less than $K(1/2)^4$. Wasn't these defined to be exactly equal to each other? That there is some $c$ value which makes $\sin(1/2) = T_3(1/2)+K(1/2)^4$? I'm interested to see because I'm still shaky on the concept and maybe there's an something I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute value bars is what does it.  You have to account for the fact that $\sin( 1/2) -T_3(1/2)$ could be negative.

Comment: I had that thought, but if they're defined to be equal, why would the absolute value cause the inequality?

Comment: @rb612 They're writing two inequalities. They're saying that both $\sin(1/2)-T_3(1/2)$ and $T_3(1/2)-\sin(1/2)$ are less than $K(1/2)^4.$